# What would be a good name for a method that is implemented in the user side and executed by 'our library' in order to decide (boolean) an operation?

Tags: javascript, naming-conventions, naming

Note: The context of this question is javascript, however is generic enough to not tie it as just as a javascript question.

We have a javascript library that needs to send a request using *http* or *https*. In order to decide which protocol to use, our library calls a method that decides which protocol should we use. That method is declared in the 'user side of our library' (as a callback?).

For the moment we have named it as *isConnectionSecure* but we are not asking that but instead the question is more like:

> *Should we use the secure protocol?*

The library is working somehow like:

```
OurSuperLibrary.api = {
    isConnectionSecure: function () {
        // Do your checks
        return true;
    }
}

var ourLibrary = new OurSuperLibrary();

// Internally, our library will call the previously declared method:
ourLibrary.doRequest();
```

Thanks.

Comment: `useHttps`? `useSecureConnection`? `shouldUseSecureConnection`? `getProtocol`?

Comment: We also thought about using *useWhatever*. However we understand that the 'use+Noun' is more like executing an operation. Thanks for your input :)

Comment: Yeah, if Javascript supported `?` in plain property names, that would be more useful. In that case I tend to do `shouldUseX`. Anyway though, this really isn't a good question for Stack Overflow. There's no "right" answer, only opinions.

Comment: Thanks for your input! It is very valuable even when it is an opinion. Mind you to point me to the correct 'stackoverfow' site for these kind of questions?